# ASP.NET Web Application suddenly cannot connect to database. Network Interface Error 26

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Express 2014.

The  issue is, it was working just fine before, now all of a sudden I can no longer connect. I have not made any changes that would affect that as far as I know. No changes in Configuration Manager. The connection test in Visual Studio succeeds. The data connection shows green in server explorer. Just when I try to access the database through my application it randomly doesn't work anymore.

I am completely baffled and have tried everything for a couple days. All other posts on the topic have been solved with checking either the server or instance name, or the remote connection settings, etc which are not applicable in my case. Are there any suggestions on this issue? I can also provide the stack trace if needed.

Comment: I'd check DNS, and make sure the sql server service (possibly the browser service) are running as well.  Is SQL Express being run locally?  If so, it sounds like the service is stopped.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried? I could list a hundred possible causes so it would be nice to know what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried everything. 

-Restarting all sql services - SQL Server, Browser and Agent, (interesting, browser and agent weren't even running before) So they are all running

- Allowing TCP and UDP ports 1433 and 1434 through firewall

- Checking to ensure remote connections are enabled

-Checking my connections string (but as I said the connection string works in visual studio)

Possibly other things, I've been trying for a while

Comment: I've also tried using the IP address instead of server name, using (LocalDB)/Server Instance, using ./Server Instance

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the issue a few days ago. Its a long shot that anyone may have the exact circumstances that caused this problem but just in case.

I migrated my application from 4.5 and 4.0 and back again, reinstalling all packages. The 4.5 framework worked for a while with Asp.NET Membership, but for some reason stopped at a point. The Identity and Identity.EntityFramework packages were installed but the using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework tag was not automatically added when I migrated back to 4.5 so the application couldn't create or access the Identity database tables created automatically when a user registers on the application for the first time. Added the tag and the DefaultConnection string in web.config and was good to go.